# mysql paged query: LIMIT m,n or select out all IDs then page by front-end?

Tags: mysql, sql

If we use traditional approach by `LIMIT m, n`, we may have these steps:

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE condition` to get total numbers and calculate how many pages;
2. `SELECT columns FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 0, 100` to show first page (assume 100 rows per page);
3. `SELECT columns FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 100, 100` when click 'next page';
4. ...

This may be very expensive because `WHERE condition` may be a full table scan. And MySQL may do this slowly on every page if cache is turned off.

So I have another way to implement this paged query:

1. `SELECT id FROM table WHERE condition` to get all IDs that match my condition. If there are huge data in this table (e.g. 1,000,000+ rows), we can limit our result size (e.g. 10,000 at most, by `LIMIT 10000`). These IDs are sent to front-end (via dynamic pages or Ajax, JavaScript code or JSON data);
2. In front-end, JavaScript choose the first 100 IDs as the first page, then request these rows, so we have `SELECT columns FROM table WHERE id IN (id_0, id_1, ..., id_99)` in back-end;
3. We have `SELECT columns FROM table WHERE id IN (id_100, id_101, ..., id_199)` when click 'next page';
4. ...

In this approach, we have only one `WHERE condition` and full data are queried by primary-key query.

This is implemented in my part-time project: (http://) www.chess-wizard.com/base/ (First page data is stored in JSP for SEO).

I share this idea to my team member but they don't agree with me :-(

Why `LIMIT m,n` must be a *standard* / *unique* way to implement paged query?

Comment: You may be looking for `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.  The first call, though, will still need to read the entire table.

Comment: Good idea. So in traditional `LIMIT m,n`, step 1 and 2 can be combined in one SQL. But next page will still be `SELECT ... WHERE condition LIMIT m,n`, isn't it?